# google app engine (gae), python-- Where to stick the cron task?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

My directory structure contains different modules..

admin, 
api,
etc

I need to create a cron job to handle updating models that are referenced in the api module.

api has it's own yaml file: api.yaml

Is it safe to assume that I should put cron.yaml, in the same location as api.yaml?

//====== Future Notes

I was successful at executing a simple cronjob with the following steps

1. cron.yaml in the same directory as api.yaml
2. api.yaml was left alone
3. I added an entry for the new route to routes.py: Route('/crontask',
       handlers.CronTaskHandler, methods=['GET'])
4. I created a handler in a separate file called cron_task_handler.py, which contained the class CronTaskHandler containing def get(self)
5. I updated the handler directory init.py to contain from cron_task_handler.py import CronTaskHandler, and put CronTaskHandler in the All list.
6. I updated the cron task via the terminal by navigating to the directory containing cron.yaml (api) and entered `appcfg.py -A <app_id> update_cron .`
7. I ran the development server
8. I visited the localhost:something/crontask url in the browser
9. I navigated to the admin console and saw my cron job under the cron jobs link.

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: something
  url: /crontask
  schedule: every 1 minutes
```

cron_task_handler.py

```
class CronTask(base_class):
    def get(self):
        print "hello, this is a cron job"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `cron.yaml` config is an app-level config, not a module config. Particular tasks may be directed to specific modules based on the content of `cron.yaml` and `dispatch.yaml`.

I'd keep it at the app's top level, as suggested in the [Module configuration doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration):

> Optional application-level configuration files (dispatch.yaml,
>   cron.yaml, index.yaml, and queue.yaml) are included in the top level
>   app directory.

Note: in multi-module apps you may **need** to use `appcfg.py update_cron` as regular `appcfg.py update` for some/all of the modules *might* not update `cron.yaml`.

Comment: So.. I don't really have a 'top-level' everything is in a module, with separate yaml files for each module.. so yes, I have a multi-module app. Are you suggesting that it should be placed, all by itself, as the only file, outside of all the modules?

Comment: Well, after testing, looks like it is safe to assume that it belongs in the same directory as api.yaml

Comment: You mean everything is in a _directory_ (the simple app case in the doc)? That works too, but it can become confusing down the road as your app grows. In this case yes, you can put the `cron.yaml` file in the same dir as well.

Comment: yeah, everything was in a directory :). I'll take what you said about confusion into consideration. Thanks

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thanks for the extra note on multi-module app, took me a while to figure this one out. Also for anyone else that finds this answer, check the note in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/an-overview-of-app-engine) that says `Services were previously called "modules"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a cron job in a specific module of your application, you can specify `target` string in your cron.yaml

```
- description: something
  url: /crontask
  schedule: every 1 minutes
  target: api
```

So here your cron job will routed to the default version of the module named `api`.

This is well documented in this wiki [About cron.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_About_cron_yaml)

> The `target` string is prepended to your app's hostname. It is usually
>   the name of a module. The cron job will be routed to the default
>   version of the named module. Note that if the default version of the
>   module changes, the job will run in the new default version.
>
> If there is no module with the name assigned to `target`, the name is
>   assumed to be an app version, and App Engine will attempt to route the
>   job to that version

.